# How do I get my Bitcoin transaction confirmed?

Tags: transactions, unconfirmed-transactions, revert-transaction, cash-app

I had a Bitcoin transaction reversal done from Cash App. And they paid the lowest fees so it has been sitting in the block chain now for over a month and it is not confirmed. How do I get it confirmed and get my funds back to my Bitcoin wallet?  Where it came from. And the amount of it is  $250.